# AWS Landing Zone - Rollback complete codepipeline after error occured post core account creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations, aws-landing-zone

I've tried to setup my AWS organization using AWS Landing Zone. This is what I have done :-

- Deploy the AWS Landing Zone based on the AWS Landing Zone initiation template
- Execute CodePipeline created by initiation template
- Core accounts were created by CodePipeline, but build gets failed while creating the CoreResources

Now, I wanted to execute the codepipeline again after doing some changes in Manifest.yaml file.

Can someone help me in understanding how can I delete the created organizations i.e. "core" and "application" and core accounts?

As far I know deletion of AWS account from Organization is not that straight forward and you have provide payment, plan details before deleting accounts created by Landing Zone. Plus, even after provided all required details AWS won't allow you to delete that account immediately.

**Is there any way to delete Organizations and core accounts created by AWS Landing Zone immediately?**

Answer (score 1):

To solve your immediate issue, there is no way to close the core accounts through the AWS Landing Zone's pipeline.

However, you can manually close the created accounts from the AWS Management Console: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/close-aws-account/

In general I would recommend using AWS Control Tower instead of the AWS Landing Zone Solution if possible. Control Tower is a Managed Service providing the Landing Zone capabilities without you having to deal with the pipeline and everything else yourself.

AWS Control Tower: https://aws.amazon.com/controltower/

Since April 22 you can also use ControlTower to set up a multi-account structure in an existing AWS Organization and enroll existing member accounts.